# Downloading simultaneously multiple files with big file lists on windows

Tags: download, wget, aria2

I am looking for a program that could download simultaneously (like, about 100 files in parallel) multiple files. The only thing is, that this program should be able to handle very big lists of files (like 200MB of links), and should work on windows.

As for now, I have tested aria2, but when I load my file list I get out of memory exception (aria is trying to use over 4Gb of memory!). Also I tried using mulk, but this thing just is not working (because I don't believe that it is loading my files list for about two hours now, when generating this list and writing onto the disk took me about a half of a minute). I haven't tried using wget yet, but as far as I know it cannot download in parallel, am I right?

Is there any software that could handle my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

With aria2, you can use `--deferred-input` option to reduce memory footprint for list input. Also making `--max-download-result` option low, such as 100, may reduce memory usage too.